# Dependencies in a windows 7 x64 driver

Tags: dll, driver, windows-7-x64

I'm writing a video capture driver for windows 7 x64.

The driver is "pin centric" and is based on the avshws example provided by Microsoft.

The driver has to use a third party dll.

No problem at compilation, linking, signing.

On installation time, I get a code 39 error.

The problem is that in load time, windows in unable to resolve the dependencies that have the "third party dll". The dependencies are "msvcrt.dll" and "kernel32.dll"

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: You cannot use that 3rd party DLL.  Drivers cannot have a dependency on kernel32, it is only available in user mode, not kernel mode.

Comment: Ok thanks. Should I change the philosophy and make an UMDF Driver?.